# Solr facet counts for specific field values

Tags: solr, faceted-search

Solr creates multi-select facet counts for me as described here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20131202095639/http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams

I also have various predefined searches that allow a user to browse the catalog. Here is one such example and its query parameters:

```
q=*:*
fq={!tag=g}genre:western
facet=on
facet.field={!ex=g}genre
facet.mincount=1
facet.limit=50
```

With this search I get up to 50 genre values in the facet list. I then go through and mark which values were selected by the user; *western* in this case. This works well except when *western* is pushed out of the top 50. So I manually add it to the list to make a total of 51. This way the user can see that it is indeed selected. The problem is I have to leave the count for *western* blank because I don't know it.

Is there a way to get counts for specific facet values such as *western* in this case? Or another approach to solve this issue?

I am using Solr 4.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

Solr allows you to create a query-based facet count by using the `facet.query` parameter. When creating a filter query (`fq`) that's based on a facet field value, I now create a corresponding facet query:

```
facet.query={!ex=g}genre:western
```

and add it to the rest of my parameters:

```
q=*:*
fq={!tag=g}genre:western
facet=on
facet.field={!ex=g}genre
facet.query={!ex=g}genre:western
facet.mincount=1
facet.limit=50
```

The facet_queries object will now be populated in the solr response:

```
{
  ...
  "facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {
      "{!ex=g}genre:western": 7
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Regardless of what is returned in the `facet_fields` object, I'm now guaranteed to have a facet count for `genre:western`. With some parsing, facet field counts can be extracted from the facet queries.